# Show single div when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Need a simple answer to this as a lot of the ones i have found have been too complex for what I need.

id like some jquery to show a div depending on a radio button selection. So if value 0 is selected, display the div?  Many thanks!

```
<p class="form-element">

<label for="MainContent_radioTerms_0">T&Cs Active</label>
<input id="MainContent_radioTerms_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$radioTerms" value="0" />
<label for="MainContent_radioTerms_1">T&Cs Inactive</label>
<input id="MainContent_radioTerms_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$radioTerms" value="1" />  

</p>

<div class="terms" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
     $('div.terms').toggle($(this).val() === '0');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/GpLd6/

Comment: Just noticed that as I couldnt get it to work, fine now though! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$radioTerms']").click(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 0)
    $("div.terms").show()
  else
    $("div.terms").hide()
});
```

Comment: This worked for me but i went for Richards. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#MainContent_radioTerms_0').is(':selected')) {
    $('.terms').show();
}
```